# While Loop / Continue Statement for Odd and Even Numbers

Tags: python

I've been working through a few exercises Python based to test my knowledge and I'm stuck on a task which I have got running but am not using the correct loops and statements.

My program needs to use two while loops and two continue statements to print odd numbers from 1 to 10. Then it will print even numbers in reverse from 8 down to 1.

I've gotten the odd to work and I'm using a step based range to do the even, not sure if there's a better way to do this?

But I'm unsure as to how I will include the two while loops and the two continue statements in my program for it to work and print into the console the same outcome as of now.

Furthermore, I'd like for my program to do include a break statement which will not print numbers higher than 6.

I'm just a bit confused on where to add this. I've been viewing many tutorials online but can't seem to find the right examples relevant.

All help and advice or where I can learn more knowledge is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for reading this!

```
for i in range(1,11):
    if(i%2!=0):
         print(i)
for i in range(8, 1, -2):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I think the idea to see effect of `continue` was to check if the number is not what you want (even in the first case), then you `continue` and bellow you `print` because you only reach that part of the loop if you have not `continue`d onto the next item.

Comment: This is odd to use such means for such a task. The question is "why?", if you can just loop through the range of even and odd numbers even without the use of conditions.

Comment: I totally agree with you Igor and I thought that would've been the most simplest way to do this task but doesn't meet the specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it with two `while` loops and two `continue` statements:

```
n = 0
while n < 10:
    n += 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(n)
while n > 1:
    n -= 1
    if n % 2 == 1:
        continue
    print(n)
```

This outputs:

```
1
3
5
7
9
8
6
4
2
```

And to avoid printing numbers higher than 6 by adding a `break` statement:

```
n = 0
while n < 10:
    n += 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        continue
    if n > 6:
        break
    print(n)
while n > 1:
    n -= 1
    if n % 2 == 1:
        continue
    print(n)
```

This outputs:

```
1
3
5
6
4
2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful indeed!